# Start multiple scripts in pm2 config

Tags: node.js, pm2

Please, help me to run this script in pm2 config

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "export NODE_ENV=production; npm run tsc:build && node -r dotenv/config dist/src/index.js",
}
```

`tsc:build` ==== `npm run clean && node_modules/.bin/tsc`

It just makes typescript compilation.

I need run this in config:

```
apps: [{
            name: 'my-app',
            script: '????',
            args: '?????',
}]
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: You should do the build before starting PM2, which should only be used to run your app. How/where are you planning to use PM2? ...from an npm script?

Comment: Thanks, Steve. The reason why I included typescript build  was to avoid compiling map files in production. Dev build has map files, and someone can ocassionlay leave them inside